# QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

Tags: c++, sql, qt, pyqt, qtsql

After setting up a table model like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


def createConnection(driverType, databaseName, hostName=None, userName=None, password=None):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase(driverType);
    db.setDatabaseName(databaseName)
    db.setHostName(hostName);
    db.setUserName(userName);
    db.setPassword(password)
    if (db.open() == False):
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error", db.lastError().text())
        return False
    return db


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    con = createConnection('QSQLITE', "testdatabase.db")

    qry = QSqlQuery()
    qry.setForwardOnly(True)

    qry.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30), lastname VARCHAR(30))");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Table createdFalse==");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (2, 'Jane', 'Doe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (3, 'James', 'Doe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (4, 'Judy', 'Doe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (5, 'Richard', 'Roe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (6, 'Jane', 'Roe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (7, 'John', 'Noakes')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (8, 'Donna', 'Doe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (9, 'Ralph', 'Roe')");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("Inserted!");

    qry.prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM names");
    if (qry.exec_() ==False):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("SelectedFalse==");

    print(con.tables(), con.primaryIndex('names').name(), con.record('names'))  # #########################

    while (qry.next()):
#        print(qry.boundValues())
        country = qry.value(1)
        print(country)

    rec = qry.record()
    cols = rec.count();

    for c in range(cols):
        print("Column {}: {}" .format(c, rec.fieldName(c)))

    qry.prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM names WHERE lastname = 'Roe'" );
    if (qry.exec_()==False ):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
        print("SelectedFalse==" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (:id, :firstname, :lastname)" );
    qry.bindValue(":id", 9 );
    qry.bindValue(":firstname", "Ralph" );
    qry.bindValue(":lastname", "Roe" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
        print(qry.lastError().text())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salaries (id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, annual INTEGER)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (1, 1000)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (2, 900)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (3, 900)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (5, 1100)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (6, 1000)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (8, 1200)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO salaries (id, annual) VALUES (9, 1200)" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:
      print("Inserted!" );

    qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM salaries" );
    if(False==qry.exec_()):
      print(qry.lastError())
    else:

      print("SelectedFalse==" );



#    con.close()

#    model = QSqlQueryModel();
#    model.setQuery( "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM names" );


    model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    model.setTable( "names" );
    model.setRelation( 0, QSqlRelation( "salaries", "id", "annual" ) );
    model.select();
#    model.setHeaderData( 0, Qt.Horizontal, ("Annual Pay") );
#    model.setHeaderData( 0, Qt.Horizontal, ("Annual Pay") );
#    model.setHeaderData( 1, Qt.Horizontal, ("First Name") );
#    model.setHeaderData( 2, Qt.Horizontal, ("Last Name") );
#    


#    model = QSqlTableModel()
    print(model.editStrategy() )
#    model.setTable( "names" );
#    model.setFilter( "lastname = 'Doe'" );
#    model.select();
#    model.removeColumn( 0 );

    view =  QTableView();
    view.setModel( model );
    view.show();

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the content is displayed properly, but after I edit the data item then press enter ,this error occurred :

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

when I close the application and restart it again ,I found the editing I did last time is not stored into the database ,anyone can fix my problem here .

Note:I did not use

```
model->removeColumn(0)
```

here.

Comment: Which query has the error return value and string? Is it at "country = qry.value(1)"? Also, why do you not use qry.first() before accessing the value?

Comment: no.only when I edit the data item then press enter ,this error occurred.

Comment: You have not answered the question. Where in the code exactly does the error occur? You pasted a very long code, not a self-contained example. Please do show the whole console output, too.

Comment: sorry,I cannot figure it out either.Perhaps you can have a try.

Comment: You cannot figure out how to paste the standard output where you print? Then, why do you print? Please show what you have on the command line.

Comment: more accurately, it is a warning  rather than an error ,because the application doesn't crash when it happened .

Comment: Please paste the output! Also, print out the last error after country = qry.value(1). Also, this is a poor way of debugging: print("Inserted!"); I would rather print out locally meaningful text, like the query...

Comment: Also, why don't you pass a hostname? It results in type error: TypeError: QSqlDatabase.setHostName(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: OK, so this is the error you are facing, too? UNIQUE constraint failed: names.id Unable to fetch row

Comment: OK, if you want to try ,you can replace this line 
con = createConnection('QSQLITE', "testdatabase.db")

with 
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName("testdatabase.db")

Comment: I already worked that around, but is there any reason why you insert literally the same, even the `id` beind the same?

Comment: Posted the answer with the explanation. Increment the id from 9 to 10 at the duplication, and it will work.

Comment: Is this still unresolved more than one year later??

Answer (score 1):

These lines are the offending:

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (:id, :firstname, :lastname)" )
qry.bindValue(":id", 9 );
qry.bindValue(":firstname", "Ralph" );
qry.bindValue(":lastname", "Roe" );
```

You basically insert the same again what you inserted before:

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO names (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (9, 'Ralph', 'Roe')");
if (qry.exec_() ==False):
    print(qry.lastError().text())
else:
    print("Inserted!");
```

The most interesting duplication is the `id` in here, and that is why you are getting the following error on the command line:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: names.id Unable to fetch row
```

It is by design that it rejects the database entries with the same unique identifier, otherwise it would not quite be unique anymore, right?

The reasonable solution would be to increment the id 9 to 10 in your code as you seem to have reserved the id from 1-9. Once, I make the change to your code, it does not produce the aforementioned error anymore.

Please also note that you are calling the createConnection function without specifying the hostname will lead to python Type Error, such as: "TypeError: QSqlDatabase.setHostName(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'".

You would probably need to handle that scenario in a more user friendly manner.

Comment: 1)after edited the data item then press enter ,the error is still there.(found by using eric python IDE).2)SQLite requires no server, so there is no need to setHostName().

Comment: 1) I cannot reproduce any error anymore. Here is the output: http://pastebin.kde.org/create?e=1 You would need to provide more context. 2) Your code does not handle the no need at all.

Comment: @user1485853: have you tried to set the delegate with something like this? view.setItemDelegate( QSqlRelationalDelegate(view) )

Comment: @user1485853: @user1485853: have you also tried `model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit);`?

Comment: @user1485853: what happens if you replace `country = qry.value(1); print(country)` with `pass`?

Comment: when I move model.setTable("names" ) and model.select() after the model.setRelation(0, QSqlRelation( "salaries", "id", "annual" ) ), the problem disappeared .just like this http://codepad.org/zqri28oj
I don't understand why ,can you explain it ?

Comment: @user1485853: I am afraid I cannot explain that based on the documentation: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#setRelation and the example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsql-relationaltablemodel-relationaltablemodel-cpp.html